# Javascript handling textarea

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, dojo, textarea

I'm a bit new to Javascript and am trying to create a delimited string from a textarea. The problem is when passing in the textarea, it adds newlines for each row on the textarea.  I need to have the entire textarea parsed into a string with a delimiter for each line (replacing the newline char).  So for example, if you passed in a textarea with the following lines (which is also how it looks when using the alert function):

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
```

It would look like: `abcd-efgh-ijkl` after parsing.

```
function submitToForm(form)
{
    var param_textarea  = form.listofplugins.value;
    var test = param_textarea.replace(/\\r?\\n/, /:/)
    alert(test);
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the doubled backslashes; just one is fine.

```
var test = param_textarea.replace(/\r?\n/g, ':')
```

Also as you see the second param should be a string. Finally the regex should end with "g" to make it a "global" replace.